# How do I code on Java/Android Studio to send and receive friend request using Volley and XAMPP?

Tags: java, php, android, xampp

Here is my user's interface or profile page:

public class UserInterface extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText ETstatus;
Button Bprofile , Bfriends , Bfav , Bmsgs , Bfeed , Badd , Bsettings , Bnew, Blogout;
TextView TVphoto , TVvideo , textView;
private String logout;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_interface);
    //Person's username go here
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVusername);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(MainPage.KEY_USERNAME));

    initTypeface();

    //Button's go here
    Bprofile = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Bprofile.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf"));

    Bfriends = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Bfriends.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf"));

    Blogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Blogout);
    Blogout.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf"));


    //EditText's go here
    ETstatus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETstatus);
    ETstatus.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf"));

}

private void initTypeface() {
    Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    TextView tittleText=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVusername);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVvideo);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVphoto);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);

    myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/SinkinSans-300Light.otf");
    tittleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
    tittleText.setTypeface(myTypeface);
}

public void onLogOutClick (View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainPage.class);
    Toast pass = Toast.makeText(UserInterface.this, "Come back soon!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    pass.show();
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

I want for it to send a friend request/chat request when the user presses a button. Also to detect whether the username is in the database.

Comment: great tutorial here -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Does this show you how to send and receive friend request?  @Tascos

Comment: @IsaacMedinaPillado Based on your posts, and the almost incremental nature of them, I think you should at least attempt a tutorial course on Android before attempting a project like a chat app. Search for 'udacity android' for the course that was co-developed by Google. Once you've improved and have specific programming questions then this site might be more fruitful.

Comment: I already know like 75% of Java I'm just very new to volley. I just need a tutorial on how to do that. Thanks tho.

Comment: no, it shows you how to send and receive data. so it could be a cow, a  donkey, a friends name or some text code.

Comment: I know that, I already have that for login and register but I want to know how to send a friend request and recieve

Comment: @IsaacMedinaPillado Android isn't just Java its the entire framework. I suspect you'll need to know about Android Service for getting data in the background and probably Google Cloud Messaging for getting notified when a new friend joins/messages your app. Again asking for tutorials are off-topic see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I know that. Thanks for your help. (Notice the sarcasm)